# Fetch from componentDidMount in React JS

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a component `<BaseMap />` and a fetch line `fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}` that I used immidiatelly after the `BaseMap` in the render method (eg. `<BaseMap fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>`).

However, somebody advised be that I should put it in `componentDidMount` instead. But how should I do it? I can't just copy `fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}` into `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchUser`? Can you post the code for `<BaseMap />`? Sounds like what they meant is that in `<BaseMap />` you should be calling `this.props.fetchUser` in `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, your components are set up as follows:

```
class Parent .... {
    ....
    fetchUser(){ 
    ....
    }

    ....
    render(){
        return ( 
        ...
            <BaseMap fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>
        ...
        );
    }
}

class BaseMap .... {
    ....
    render(){
        let user = this.props.fetchUser();
        return ( 

            <div> { ...use user here ... }</div>

        );
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

What you are being advised to do is to take the call to fetchUser out of BaseMap components render method and move to its componentDidMount method. Then store the user in the state of the component and use it from there.

```
class BaseMap .... {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={user:null};
     }

    componentDidMount(){
        let user = this.props.fetchUser();
        this.setState({user:user});
    }

    render(){
        return ( 
            <div> {this.state.user?  
                       ...use user here ...
                        : "loading data"
            }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `fetchUser` method to `BaseMap` component and then call the method in componentDidMount  as `this. fetchUser()`. Else pass method as props and access it in your target component.